# Simple Tower Property Question

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am wondering the following is true. It seems to be true because if we know $X$ and $Y$, we know $X+Y$. So we may apply tower property. Any formal reasoning if it is true?

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z|X,Y]|X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[Z|X+Y]$

Moreover, is the following true

$\mathbb{E}[Z|X,Y]=\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$

given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. You are right. I edited it.

Comment: @hejseb "If Z,X and Z,Y are independent, then E(Z|X,Y)=E(Z)." Absolutely not. Note that (Z,X) independent and (Z,Y) independent does not imply that Z and (X,Y) are independent.

Comment: @Did Ah yes. I mean if $Z$ is independent of $X, Y$ and not them by themselves. Thanks for pointing that out. That aside I think user42930 had it wrong in the question (w.r.t. what s/he wanted to know).

Answer (score 0):

Both

- $\mathbb{E}[Z|X,Y]=\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z$ and $Y$ are independent?
- $\mathbb{E}[Z|X,Y]=\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$ given that $Z$ and $X$ are independent and $Z$ and $Y$ are independent?

have the counterexample of four equally-probable combinations

```
X Y Z

0 0 0
1 0 1
0 1 1 
1 1 0
```